# How to change innerHTML or innerText of element via attribute in real-time

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the `innerHTML` of `.container` in real-time via `setAttribute('data-content', 'value changed');`. Currently, I am appending `innerHTML` via `.container.innerHTML = .container.getAttribute('data-content');`

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.innerHTML = container.getAttribute('data-content');

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

// before clicking on button
console.log(container.getAttribute('data-content'));

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  container.setAttribute('data-content', 'Value Changed!!');
  console.log(container.getAttribute('data-content'));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" data-content="Hello, World!"></div>
<button class="btn">Change Attribute Value</button>
```

Comment: Just change it as `container.textContent = 'Value Changed!!';` inside `clickListener`. Simple

Comment: There is no real way to have the change in a variable value reflect "live" in the DOM automatically, you will always have to set the element content yourself some way or other.

Comment: @CBroe I think we can do it in `react` using `hooks`.

Comment: Sure, that's possible - but you did not ask about or tag this with react. And it is still a custom implementation of functionality that does not natively exist then.

Comment: @CBroe that is the main problem I want to do in this vanilla `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as folks in comments said - You could create this binding with using some kind of "JS framework", where you would define binding between the attribute and the "value HTML/text value of `<div>` tag.

But in the plain JS/html, you have to set this value manually.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.innerHTML = container.getAttribute('data-content');

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

// before clicking on button
console.log(container.getAttribute('data-content'));

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  container.setAttribute('data-content', 'Value Changed!!');
  console.log(container.getAttribute('data-content'));


  // Added line
  container.innerHTML = container.getAttribute('data-content');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" data-content="Hello, World!"></div>
<button class="btn">Change Attribute Value</button>
```

Comment: what if I want to change the value constantly.

Comment: Ideally you would create function and whenever you will want to change this value, you call this function. And in the function you will update the attribute + update the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr())** function in CSS for pseudo element

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

// before clicking on button
console.log(container.getAttribute('data-content'));

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  container.setAttribute('data-content', 'Value Changed!!');
  console.log(container.getAttribute('data-content'));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
.container::before{
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" data-content="Hello, World!"></div>
<button class="btn">Change Attribute Value</button>
```

Comment: It is not what I want!